# What is the difference between file size in ls -l and du-sh?

Tags: files, ls, disk-usage

I have a most confusing questing that bothered me for years. What is the difference between the file size given by ls -l and du -sh *.

```
GRILL:/user/MAIL/DATA>ll
total 270
drwxr-xr-x  11 user     users         1024 Mar 21  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 user     users           96 May 28  2008 ..
drwxr-xr-x  10 user     users         1024 Jun 14 09:40 Rod
drwxr-xr-x   3 user     users           96 Sep 17  2010 Atlas
drwxr-xr-x  2339 user     users       132096 Jun 14 15:00 Admin    
drwxr-xr-x   3 user     users           96 Jul 11  2014 DE
drwxr-xr-x   5 user     users           96 Jun 14 08:30 Express
drwxr-xr-x   3 user     users           96 Sep 17  2010 Deferred
drwxr-xr-x   2 user     users           96 Feb 10  2009 Imagi
drwxr-xr-x   6 user     users         1024 Jul 11  2014 NO
drwxr-xr-x   3 user     users         2048 Mar 21  2013 SE
-rw-r--r--   1 user     users           55 Mar 21  2013 cmd

GRILL:/user/MAIL/DATA>du -sk *
6723    Rod
0       Atlas
435494  Admin
2       DE
111273  Express
2       Deferred
0       Imagi
541     NO
12      SE
1       cmd
```

The size of Admin in `ls -l` is `132096`, I tried removing 400000+ files from Admin directory and I didnt find the space reduced even a bit.

Whereas `du -sk` gives the size as `435494`. Which one is the original size of the file and what is the difference between them? Could anyone please elaborate?

Comment: See [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311)

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/290088/what-is-the-difference-between-du-h-and-ls-lh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For files, `ls -l file` shows (among other things) the size of `file` in bytes, while `du -k file` shows the space occupied by `file` on disk (in units of 1 kB = 1024 bytes).  Since disk space is allocated in blocks, the size indicated by `du -k` is always slightly larger than the space indicated by `ls -kl` (which is the same as `ls -l`, but in 1 kB units).

For directories, `ls -ld dir` shows (among other things) the size of the list of filenames (together with a number of attributes) of the files and subdirectories in `dir`.  This is just the list of filenames, not the files' or subdirectories' contents.  So this size increases when you add files to `dir` (even when files are empty), but it stays unchanged when one of the files in `dir` grows.

However, when you delete files from `dir` the space from the list is not reclaimed immediately, but rather the entries for deleted files are marked as unused, and are later recycled (this is actually implementation-dependent, but what I described is pretty much the universal behavior these days).  That's why you may not see any changes in `ls -ld` output when you delete files until much later, if ever.

Finally, `du -ks dir` shows (an estimate of) the space occupied on disk by all files in `dir`, together with all files in all of `dir`'s subdirectories, in 1 kB = 1024 bytes units.  Taking into account the description above, this has no relation whatsoever with the output of `ls -kld dir`.

Comment: About the non-reclaiming, that is true of most FS with traditional structures, but not of some modern file systems like ZFS or BTRFS.

Comment: Also a correction on `the size indicated by du is always slightly larger than the space indicated by ls`, sparse files will have less space used on disk (and thus reported by `du`) depending on the size and number of holes. I'm unsure if `du` is also capable of taking into account/recognising filesystem-level block or file compression, which would make `ls` further report a larger logical filesize over `du`s physical usage.

Comment: @Hashbrown not only sparse files but transparently compressed files and [resident/inline files](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data) (for example in Btrfs, ext4 and NTFS) will also consume less space on disk so will have du reported smaller sizes. You'll need `du --apparent-size` to get the actual size

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l` only shows file sizes at 1 level.

`du` will show folder sizes recursively (sum of file sizes under the folder).