# Output of 2 commands get the difference (ls vs du)

Tags: text-processing, awk, ls, disk-usage

So analyzing an issue at work I found that, when I created some datafiles on Oracle, the datafiles didn't reserve the space in the Filesystem, so I went to the `sapdata` filesystem where I put the datafiles and for my surprise an `ls -ltr` shows the files with the specified weight when I created the datafile, but a `du -gs` says it was 0.00 so to compare I made this two commands:

A)

```
find ./sapdata* -name "temp*" -type f -exec du -gs {} \;
```

B)

```
find ./sapdata* -name "temp*" -type f -exec ls -ltr {} \; | awk '{printf ("%.2f\t%s\n", $5/1024/1024/1024,$9)}'
```

Have in mind, this commands are like this because this is Unix, not Linux, I can't use `-printf` or `-h`, I have to use `-g` and I have to divide by 1024 to get to GB on the `ls`.

The last one result on an output that is equal to the output of the first one, but the second one using the information from `ls -ltr`.

In practice it's everything ok, I manage to see the difference and we are looking at the issue, but I want to go a step forward in two ways:

1. Mix both results into something that tells me which files are different in one line
2. Mix both results and get a "Health status" of the comparisons, this would be useful to make a monitoring script.

The output I get from this commands are the following for an example

A) Gives me:

```
15.63   ./sapdata19/temp_1/temp.data1
25.31   ./sapdata20/temp_2/temp.data2
```

B) Gives me:

```
15.63   ./sapdata19/temp_1/temp.data1
0.00    ./sapdata20/temp_2/temp.data2
```

So from solution 1 I would want something like

```
                         DU                                            DIFF                                    LS
--------------------------------------------------------   ----------   --------------------------------------------------------
15.63   ./sapdata19/temp_1/temp.data1    OK          15.63   ./sapdata19/temp_1/temp.data1
25.31   ./sapdata20/temp_2/temp.data2    FAILED   0.00    ./sapdata20/temp_2/temp.data2
```

Or something similar, the headers are not needed although I know it's possible

For solution 2 I would want something like

```
Health=50%
Number of Failed=1
Total Number of Datafiles=2
List of Failed=
./sapdata20/temp_2/temp.data2
```

Maybe the last solution I can do it without much issues with a BASH script, but the first one since I want it in one line I'm not sure how to do it. I guess with `xargs` and `diff` or maybe a for inside `awk` but I'm not sure.

---

- To Answer @roaima:

  No, this is not an issue about the difference between `du` and `ls`, I know there is a difference but usually this difference is not meaningful, now with temp files on Oracle it could be meaningful. I'm not entirely sure how Oracle work since I'm not a DBA but I have to do some simple task like adding datafiles from `brtools`.

  Point is, imagine you have a 100G sapdata FS on `/oracle/SID/sapdata1` (a oracle for a SAP instance). If you add 2 datafiles of 25G to that `sapdata1` the `sapdata` will now have 50G used, 50G available, now you add 2 temp files of 20G each. So you will have 90G used space on sapdata1, but no, you will have 50G used represented by the sum of each file that you find with `du`, then you go another day and if the temp wasn't used they will remain as 1024K (empty file size) and you do a `df -Ph` and say "Hey I have 50G free I can add 2 25G datafiles on my main tablespace", you go and add that, the question here would be, is Oracle going to understand that there is actually no space on the FS because the temp files have a weight that is not represented on DF? well in my opinion he wouldn't know and will let you add those 2 extra data files.

  On this point you will have 4 datafiles an 0G free on the FS, plus 2 20G tempfiles that does not occupy space on FS, if you sum the find of a `du` the sum will be 100G, if you sum the find of a ls it will be 140G on a 100G FS.

  Meaning that when the Oracle database try to actually USE those temp files it will not be able to do it and fail, or it will automatically resize the temp file to whatever space is left? I'm not sure but if there is no control there it will fail, and it wouldn't be very good to have that failing on a Productive environment.

  Oracle create those temp files without allocating the space to create them fast, but in my opinion it could cause some issue not only confusion.
  Sorry if my english is not the best.
- @Paul_pedant
  Sorry I forgot to point that this is Unix, not Linux, unix find have `-print` not `-printf`, either way I may be able to do this shorter with `-print` on find but I like to use `awk` hehe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between file size in ls -l and du-sh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371238/what-is-the-difference-between-file-size-in-ls-l-and-du-sh)

Comment: Oracle files representing tables can be sparse files. They only consume disk blocks when they are actually written to. `find` even has a `-printf %S` option to report sparseness.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification in your question. This is overcommit. Wouldn't it be better to ask the ORACLE database system for its intended tablespace sizes?