# File bytes was increased after copying files from centos to centos server

Tags: linux, centos, rsync, file-copy

I copied files from one server to another server using `rsync`. The folder file byte size, as measured with `du -sb <folder>`, increased from 31,755,289,904 bytes to 31,755,505,579.

I'm not sure how this was happened.

Both servers are CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core).

Please help.

Comment: How are you measuring `folder file byte size`?

Comment: by using du -sb <folder>

Comment: Folder byte size is pretty much irrelevant. What's important is the sizes of the files in the directory

Comment: Please include in your question the precise rsync command you used. Were any of the files in the source considered to be _sparse_?

Comment: As this is a Q&A site, your post will be better if you add an explicit question to it. For now the post is only a story, not a question. Improve it by [edit]ing. Note "why?", "how?" or "is the copy fine?" are different questions with different possible answers, so don't let us guess what your question really is.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/561302/77996

Answer (score 1):

I can cite the previous question [What is the difference between file size in ls -l and du-sh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371238/what-is-the-difference-between-file-size-in-ls-l-and-du-sh), but I'll summarize:

`du` measures the amount of space a file consumes in the filesystem.  Space for files is allocated by filesystems in "blocks" of 1kbytes, but with very large disks the size of the blocks can be larger.

So a file that's a few hundred kbytes according to `ls -l` will consume one full block of the filesystem.  Other files can't "share" that block, so the full size of the block is tablulated against the file by `du`.  `ls -l` reports the number of bytes used by the file's contents and ignores the extra unused space in the block.

Traditionally for most disks up to a couple of terabytes in size, Linux filesystems use blocks of 1 kbyte (1024 bytes).  On larger disks (like 4+TB), the filesystem blocks are often 4 kbytes.  `ls -l` may show the file is a couple hundred kbytes in size, but on disk it uses 1 block (1 kbyte) and `du` shows that.  On a different server, if the disk is much larger, the file will still consume one block of space, but the block is 4 k bytes / 4096 bytes.

Everything else about the two servers can be exactly the same, but if the filesystems holding the file have different block sizes on the servers, the `du` command will report the file consumes different amounts of room in the filesystems.

Comment: OK but OP uses du's **-b** option (equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1') therefore, result should be independent of filesystem"s blocksize.